# R CMD Rserve: not found on Mac OS X

Tags: r, rserve

Anyone know running the command line for Rserve on Mac OS X

```
R CMD Rserve --no-save
```

generates a

> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd: line 62: exec:
>   Rserve: not found

(works fine on Linux)

however, starting it from an R console, as in

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve();
```

works fine. But I really want to start it from the command line on Mac OS X.

Comment: I think you should post this question (with a more complete description of your versions of OSX, R and Rserve) on the R-Mac-SIG list. You could wait for @SimonUrbanek to log back on SO, but I think this is not working as described in the help pages and deserves a look by its maintainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me with R 2.15.2 and Rserve "1.7-0". I am pretty sure it is because don't have the library loaded when R is starting. You can probably add library("Rserve") to your .Rprofile and it should work since it will load the library when R is started. The namespace the Rserve and run.Rserve exported.

```
chinshaw$ cat NAMESPACE 
useDynLib(Rserve)
export(Rserve, self.ctrlEval, self.ctrlSource, self.oobSend, self.oobMessage, run.Rserve)
```

Comment: This did indeed turn out to be because I was using 1.6 binaries. Works fine with 1.7 source.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Mac OS X 10.8.5 running Rserve 1.7-3 binaries, and R 2.15.0.

I have a workaround by issuing

```
> export REXEC=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rserve/libs/x86_64
> cd $REXEC
> export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
> ./Rserve
```

But > R CMD Rserve is broken for me.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to symlink Rserve like this:

`ln -s /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/Rserve/libs/Rserve /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rserve`